# Java подключиться к прокси

Tags: java, proxy

Как подключиться к прокси в Java? Мне нужно, чтобы программа меняла внешний IP компьютера. В интернете куча статей по подключению по URL через прокси, но это не то, что мне нужно.

Comment: А что вам нужно?

Comment: Добрый день, Сергей! Мне нужно, чтобы программа меняла внешний IP компьютера